# Playwright add fields in json test result

Tags: json, playwright, playwright-test

Could we add custom fields in json test report in Playwright?

eg, currently, I have this in my json test report
[image]

I would like to add the page url in the test-report, since we do not have that information right now. Are we able to add it?

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom annotations](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#custom-annotations):

```js
test('annotated test', async ({ page }) => {
    test.info().annotations.push({ type: 'your type', description: 'description text' })
    // your test
})
```

They are added to the json reporter as an annotation under each test:

```json
...
              "tests": [
                {
                  "timeout": 30000,
                  "annotations": [
                    {
                      "type": "your type",
                      "description": "description text"
                    }
                  ],
...
```